# Merging from multiple worksheets into one worksheet but its format is not like the original one

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new into coding, so please help me.

This code is from kutools.I want to merge all the worksheets into one sheet, but the "combined" sheet should be the last of the worksheets. So I have edited some parts of the code.

when I run, it turns abnormal, it's very different if you put the combined sheets in sheets(1). 
it seems the format in original sheets like font, length of column, has varied a lot. The result is like I have done "PASTE VALUE" only. It's very different if I change the destination in sheets(1).

Sorry for bad English, here's one example of my sheet, all sheets have the same format and header.
[image: Snapshot]

Here's the result when I combined all data in new sheets, on the last sheet named "RAW" the format has gone.
[image: Snapshot of RAW worksheet]

The format is very important for presenting reports in a proper presentable way to Seniors.

would you please help me for better format?

And here's the code.

```
 Sub merge()
     Dim P As Integer
     Dim lastws As Worksheet
     On Error Resume Next
     'Sheets(1).Select
     'Worksheets.Add
     'Sheets(1).Name = "RAW"
     'Set lastsht = After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)

     'Worksheets(Worksheets.Count).Select
     'Worksheets.Add
     'Worksheets(Worksheets.Count).Name = "RAW"

     Set lastws = Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
     lastws.Name = "RAW"
     'nice udah bisa

     Sheets(1).Active
     Range("A1").EntireRow.Select
     Selection.Copy Destination:=Sheets("RAW").Range("A1")
     For P = 2 To Sheets.Count
         Sheets(P).Activate
         Range("A5").Select
         Selection.CurrentRegion.Select
         Selection.Offset(1, 0).Resize(Selection.Rows.Count - 1).Select
         Selection.Copy Destination:=Sheets("RAW").Range("A65536").End(xlUp)(2)
     Next
     Sheets("RAW").Select
     MsgBox ("Here is merged data!")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of `On Error Resume Next` and you'll be able to see errors in your own code, the reason you don't get a heading is because `sheets(1).active` is not valid code you're just copying the 1st row from raw back over itself at the moment. `columns("a:k").autofit` will resize the columns in your destination sheet. As for the rest of the formatting, you haven't actually shown it in your first sheet, but a straight `.copy destination:=whatever` as you have used should preserve cell formatting fine

Comment: halo hello world, if `sheets(1).active` is invalid code, could you give me an example of right code??
and what's the best answer to replace the invalid code??